# How to translate matrix information into simple x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, raphael

I have an SVG file wich i'm editing in illustrator. I've already used the paths information inside this file to create a Raphael object with it. What I want to do now is to add text to some parts of the drawing. The thing is that Raphael would only accept X and Y coodinates, and the text inside the SVG file is a matrix.

Basicly I need to turn this:

```
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 583 562)" font-size="12">Argentina</text>
```

into something like this:

```
var t = paper.text(x, y, "Argentina");
```

Is that possible? I've also tried turning the text into outlines, but the resulting path is to complex, and I prefer something lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear your problem. I looked into these issues when I wrote an SVG to Raphael converter (One of the first).
The converter takes all transforms out of path and changes all coordinates from relative to Absolute. In svg Text there is a lot to get your head around. The coverter I wrote offers some support for converting Text. I thought you might try putting your SVG through the converter and see what javascript it chucks out with reference to text.
The converter puts out at least a couple of formats but the 2 you might try are the default output.
Go to the [converter page](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php)

Upload your SVG just using the defaults. When you click "Collect Raphael" that will take you to the interactive javascript produced. This only deals with paths to see what work was done with Text click the "or page" link...

If you need help, I will check back...

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case the matrix just translates to `x: 583` and `y: 562`, but if your element is scaled or rotated then these values will be misleading.

You can apply transform matrices directly in Raphael, all you need to to is...

```
transformation = Raphael
     .matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 583, 562)
     .toTransformString();

text = paper
    .text(0, 0, "Argentina")
    .attr("font-size", 12)
    .transform(transformation)​
```

Now, if don't like applying transformations on your elements, you can work out the matrix transformations into a more human readable format by doing `console.log(transformation)`, this will give you a string such as `t100,100r30,100,100s2,2,100,100` which is well explained in [Raphael's documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform)